# Verifying That A Collection Is A Partition of $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, integer-partitions

Can someone possibly explain this to me, I'm having difficulties visualizing it:

 For each $r\in\mathbb{R}$, let $A_r=\{(x, y, z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 : x+y+z=r\}$. How can I tell if this is a partition of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

EDIT: Okay, so I pretty much understand this problem, but what if it were like:
For each $r\in\mathbb{R}$, let $A_r=\{(x, y, z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 : x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2\}$. Is it correct to think that it would not be a partition because $A_r$ and $A_{-r}$ would have a value in common?

Comment: What properties do you need to verify? Which ones are you having trouble with?

Comment: It's just trying to determine if _A_ is a partition of R3 or not. Like for any _r_ there are infinitely many triples of real numbers that can sum to it - does that make it not a partition?

Comment: That's not the question I'm asking. There are some properties that a partition satisfies. What are those properties? Which ones are you having trouble showing hold in this case?

Comment: In your second example, $A_r$ and $A_{-r}$ would not simply have a value in common; rather they would both be the same set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall the definition of a partition $\mathcal A\subseteq P(\mathbb R^3)$:

1. For every $x\in\mathbb R^3$ there exists $A\in\mathcal A$ such that $x\in A$.
2. For every $A,B\in\mathcal A$ if $A\neq B$ then $A\cap B=\varnothing$.
3. $\varnothing\notin\mathcal A$.

If so, we first need to make sure that every vector is somewhere in the partition, which is trivial: if $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3$ then let $r=x+y+z$ and thus $(x,y,z)\in A_r$.

Now we need to see that those are all disjoint, which is again simple. If $(x,y,z)$ in $A_r$ and in $A_s$ then $s=x+y+z=r$ so the intersection cannot be nonempty for $r\neq s$.

Lastly, we need to see that for every $r\in\mathbb R$ we have that $A_r\neq\varnothing$ and indeed $(r,0,0)\in A_r$.

---

As for the edited question: indeed in order to show that a certain collection is *not* a partition we only need to contradict one of the three properties above. Just as you write, $(1,0,0)\in A_1\cap A_{-1}$ proving that the partition is not pairwise disjoint.

Comment: Ok, the logic makes sense (for every problem like this I just have to test those three conditions). But how would I draw this partition? I just can't visualize dividing up R3 like this.

Comment: @roboguy12: There is no guarantee that you can visualize a partition.  For example, let me partition $R^3$ into ten sets, being the mod 10 sum of the first 10 decimal digits after the point of each coordinate.  I can't imagine that one.  In this case, the sets are planes perpendicular to (1,1,1).

Comment: Not everything you can draw or imagine. Try to understand which vectors would be mapped to $1$; try to understand how the same idea would work on $\mathbb R^2$ and use that to understand how it would look like in $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I'm just new to this is all..does the logic in my edit make sense?

Comment: @roboguy12: Yes, indeed it makes sense.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much!

Comment: @roboguy: For $x+y+z=r$, the partition is not hard to visualize. For any specific $r$, we get a plane, so you get a division of space into a bunch of parallel planes. To step down one dimension for ease of drawing, the lines $x+y=r$ are a bunch of parallel lines with slope $-1$, and we are dividing up the plane into such lines.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  Can any point be in more than one $A_r$?  Are all points in some $A_r$?